# How do I build an Ionic 4 app to run in a folder?

Tags: ionic-framework

When I build my Ionic 4 app, it presumes to run at the root of the domain. It puts `<base href="/" />` in the Index.html, and so all subsequent requests target the root of the domain. I can make it work in a folder by changing the base to `<base href="." />`, but a little voice tells me I shouldn't be modifying a generated file.

Where is the configuration variable to let me run my app from a folder if I want to? Do I need to know the name of the folder at build time?

Answer (score 0):

You can just go `ionic serve` in any folder and it will serve your application. If you mean in an production environment you'd run `ionic cordova build <platform>` and it'll generate the `.apk` if you specified the android environment or it will generate an XCode project if you specified iOS.

I am however unsure which platform you are building for. So your results may vary if you're building for the browser platform.

Hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: The question doesn't relate to cordova. I'm a web developer, so it never occurred to me to specify "the browser platform", but yes I'm talking about the browser platform! I do `npm run build` to get a www folder. I want to serve this folder from a directory below my web root, not the root of the domain.

Comment: Do people use Ionic for web apps?

Comment: People generally don't use Ionic for web apps, since it is basically a wrapper for Angular it is easier to build an angular project directly for web apps. Ionic leans very heavily towards the mobile development side of things.